# Data Migration from SQL Serever Express 2008 R2 to MySQL 5

Tags: mysql, sql-server-express

I am trying to copy a database from SQL Server 2008 Express to MySQL using the MYSQL Migration Toolkit on Windows and keep getting the following connection error.

```
Connecting to source database and retrieve schemata names.
Initializing JDBC driver ... 
Driver class MS SQL JDBC Driver
Opening connection ... 
Connection jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1433/ePacro2.0;user=sa;password=xxxxxx;charset=utf-8;domain=
The list of schema names could not be retrieved (error: 0).
ReverseEngineeringMssql.getSchemata :Network error IOException: Connection refused: connect
Details: 
net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ConnectionJDBC2.<init>(ConnectionJDBC2.java:372)
net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ConnectionJDBC3.<init>(ConnectionJDBC3.java:50)
net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:178)
java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
com.mysql.grt.modules.ReverseEngineeringGeneric.establishConnection(ReverseEngineeringGeneric.java:141)
com.mysql.grt.modules.ReverseEngineeringMssql.getSchemata(ReverseEngineeringMssql.java:99)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
com.mysql.grt.Grt.callModuleFunction(Unknown Source)
```

Would you have any idea why this is failing?

I've also tried to export from SQL express 2008 but it won't let me choos a MySQL ODBC connector for my destination.

Answer (score 0):

Having ODBC driver for MS SQL server database, you could try [Data Import tool](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/data-export-import.html) in [dbForge Studio for MySQL](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/).